# Getting json string from api but how to use it in flutter app?

Tags: json, flutter, api

```
var res = await http.get(Uri.parse("SomeEndPoint"));
var data1 = jsonDecode(res.body);
```

this is my code what next i do to use it in flutter app

Comment: Can you also put the sample return of the data you having

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can get all the information in the data, for example:

```
final data = jsonDecode(res.body);

// For example this data looks like this:

// {
//    "id": "hZs68Hs7u",
//    "message": "Hello",
// }
```

Now you can access the fields in it and do whatever you want:

```
final String id = data["id"];
final String message = data["message"];
```